# SwiftUI Button with double functionality - Normal tap and also continuous action when I stay on button

Tags: button, swiftui

I am attempting to make a button that has the following specific functionality:

- React to an individual tap
- React to a long press action DURING the press, NOT only at the end of the press action.
  Example: When rotating an object, an individual tap rotates it by for example ten degrees. But when I hold on the button, it rotates at a specific speed, for example 45 degrees per second. When I let go of the button, the continuous action stops.

The following reacts with incorrect behavior. It registers individual taps and long gestures incorrectly. No luck with the continuous action when holding.

```
 Button {
                print("Tapped")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle")
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(
                LongPressGesture()
                    .onChanged({ _ in
                        print("Long tap gesture")
                    })

            )
```

How can I implement the required actions with one button?

Comment: Here's a useful link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-use-gestures-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a little complicated because you have to support tap and long gesture functions within one button.

If you try to solve it by implementing it with a button or by putting in a tap gesture & a long gesture at the same time, there are many problems, so instead, we decided to distinguish whether it is a tap or a long gesture by the time from the beginning to the end within the long gesture. ( isTappedTime )

If it is shorter than isTappedTime, it is separated by tabs, and if it is longer than this, it is treated as a long gesture.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var timer: Timer? = nil
    @State private var startTime: Date? = nil
    @State private var elapsedTime: Double = 0
    @State private var isTappedTime: Double = 0.5
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotationAngle))
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: Double.infinity, pressing: { isPressing in
                if isPressing {
                    print("onLongPressGesture start")
                    self.startTime = Date()
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
                        if let startTime = self.startTime {
                            self.elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                            print("Timer is at: \(self.elapsedTime)")
                            if self.elapsedTime > self.isTappedTime {
                                self.rotationAngle += 5
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("onLongPressGesture end")
                    self.timer?.invalidate()
                    self.timer = nil
                    if let startTime = self.startTime {
                        self.elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                        print("Final elapsed time: \(self.elapsedTime)")
                        if self.elapsedTime <= self.isTappedTime {
                            self.rotationAngle += 90
                        }
                    }
                    self.startTime = nil
                }
            }) {
                // Nothing here
            }
    }
}
```

[Here is a video testing the above code.](https://vimeo.com/845598111?share=copy)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, thank you very much!